# Joomla Modal Popup to show only a certain portion of a page

Tags: php, view, joomla, popup, modal-dialog

I like to ask is there any way that joomla modal popup can show only a certain part of a page.

Right now I am using below

```
<a class="osmodal" href="http://www.abc.com/index.php?tmpl=component")?>" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 900, y: 500}, onClose: function() {}}">
```

I understand and have use the above &tmpl=component which will allow a modal popup to show the component section of a page.

Right now I am looking for a solution to allow a modal popup to show only a certain part of the component section in above page. Could there be a way to define by class?

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

However, you have two workarounds that can get you there:

1. **Ajax**

   Implement an ajax call for the same url, in the callback function you can parse the result and remove the part you don't want.  A bit difficult, additionally you will have to rely on the component producing the same output consistently, or the script will break.
2. **Server**

   Change the component, add a parameter or invoke through a task, then render the request as you want.